# Disable Ajax Add to Cart on product page

Tags: magento-1, ajax, shopping-cart

In our web-shop, we use an AJAX add to cart, so the page doesn't have to reload. But when the order is bigger than the stock, the ajax keeps loading and doesn't show a message the order isn't available.

**The console error is 503 (Service Unavailable)**

Is there a way to fix this or to disable ajax add to cart only on the product page but keep it working on other pages!

**Error Log:**

> a:5:{i:0;s:81:"De gevraagde hoeveelheid voor "Restorative Hair Mask
>   250 ml" is niet beschikbaar.";i:1;s:1539:"#0
>   /home/users/beaxmftp/beautyballoon.nl/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Cart.php(284):
>   Mage::throwException('De gevraagde ho...')
>       #1 /home/users/beaxmftp/beautyballoon.nl/app/code/local/Cmsmart/AjaxCart/controllers/IndexController.php(154):
>   Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart->addProduct('53', Array)
>       #2 /home/users/beaxmftp/beautyballoon.nl/app/code/local/Cmsmart/AjaxCart/controllers/IndexController.php(67):
>   Cmsmart_AjaxCart_IndexController->tryaddAction(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product),
>   Array)
>       #3 /home/users/beaxmftp/beautyballoon.nl/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418):
>   Cmsmart_AjaxCart_IndexController->indexAction()
>       #4 /home/users/beaxmftp/beautyballoon.nl/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
>       #5 /home/users/beaxmftp/beautyballoon.nl/app/code/community/ArtsOnIT/OfflineMaintenance/Controller/Router/Standard.php(46):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
>       #6 /home/users/beaxmftp/beautyballoon.nl/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172):
>   ArtsOnIT_OfflineMaintenance_Controller_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
>       #7 /home/users/beaxmftp/beautyballoon.nl/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
>       #8 /home/users/beaxmftp/beautyballoon.nl/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
>       #9 /home/users/beaxmftp/beautyballoon.nl/index.php(89): Mage::run('', 'store')
>       #10 {main}";s:3:"url";s:98:"/ajaxcart/index/index/?form_key=hGxTgs9rzs7WqBfZ&product=53&related_product=&qty=5&_=1446135436562";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:2:"nl";}

Comment: which extension you are using for ajax add to cart? do you have any live URL?

Comment: @Sjoerd Have you checked your server logs for potential PHP errors? 503 errors typically mean you have a fatal PHP error and/or an exception happening on the request. This log would give you a pointer on where the bug is causing the problem. (and if you find it, go ahead and add the log entry to the question here if it doesn't make sense to you)

Comment: i've added the error log to the question

Answer (score 0):

> To disable ajax add to cart only on the product page find out product
>   details page from your module and comment out code for ajax Add To
>   Cart

Answer (score 0):

This code is trying to see if ordering a specific amount is possible, but then does not handle the exception.

Got full code?

[Edit]

I guess this came with the template, the quality is horrible.
Aside from the fact that the private non-static method tryAddAction is called statically, it's also not guarded against exceptions and is well known exception for Magento developers that Magento throws there.
This code will not run in developer mode, therefore you should not run it in production. The choice of Ajax carts is legion, no need to use the one that came with the template, although I understand the convenience.

Comment: You can find the full code here: http://codepad.co/s/6d91f6

Answer (score 0):

in your `addtocart.phtml`

```
app\design\frontend\[Theme]\template\catalog\product\view\addtocart.phtml
```

> button type='button'

change to

> buttton type='submit'

Comment: Anyone help me to solve add to cart error in CMS Page, code -> https://justpaste.it/6tp4f error message Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0  in C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\local\Cmsmart\AjaxCart\controllers\IndexController.php on line 209

Comment: error in controller file not in the phtml file

Comment: can you pls explain in brief?

Answer (score 0):

**Step-1:** 
Open this file ‘addtocart.phtml’ file available on below location.
vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\view\addtocart.phtml

**Step-2:** 
Now look for the below code available around line no-44 inside file.

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "Magento_Catalog/product/view/validation": {
                "radioCheckboxClosest": ".nested"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

And replace that code with given code.

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "#product_addtocart_form": {
        "Magento_Catalog/product/view/validation": {
            "bindSubmit": true,
            "radioCheckboxClosest": ".nested"
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

**Step-3:**

Lastly navigate to backend admin dashboard and make following change in configuration.

Store->Configuration->Sales->Checkout->Shopping Cart->After Adding a Product Redirect to Shopping Cart to Yes.